# Sticker on passport

Tags: airports, airport-security

I had a sticker placed on my passport at Brisbane airport (inside last page) that states:

SECURITY
DO NOT REMOVE
05/11/18

It's blue and grayish.

Would I have a problem or denied boarding if I have this sticker going back to Australia?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: Did you fly to the United States from Brisbane on the 5th November 2018?

Comment: Who put that stickers?

Answer (score 4):

I've always had them placed on the back of the Passport.  They are meant to indicate the document has been inspected, *that day*.

> Would I have a problem...going **back** to Australia?

No.  The country of origin won't care and it's essentially expired in Australia.

I and many others have removed them *after completing that journey*.  No problems yet.

Comment: Indeed.  How could there be a problem, after all? How would anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not have a problem. It says `DO NOT REMOVE`, so don't remove it.

Comment: Are you serious? That’s only valid for that travel day and flight. I have several such on my passport.

Comment: Me too. I just leave them there, they're not a problem.

Comment: *so don't remove it* Ever??

Comment: @MJeffryes I always take them off when I'm done traveling.  In fact I think it's safe to remove them once you've boarded the plane.